# Why won't my 2km Egg hatch?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have an egg which is refusing to hatch. As you can see in the image, it is at 1.99/2km:

[image: egg stuck at 1.99]

I've walked at least an extra 2km since it got to this, and restarted both the app and phone. I've searched and didn't spot anyone with a similar scenario to mine.

**Update**: It's now on 2/2km, so I'm hoping it hatches soon.

Comment: Maybe it thinks you are GPS spoofing

Comment: The app is not very accurate at tracking distance. [This](http://kotaku.com/the-uncracked-secrets-of-pokemon-go-egg-hatching-1784339902) Kotaku article's writer compares its distance with a running tracker and finds the output completely different.

Comment: I don't think it thinks I'm spoofing as I've been collecting pokestops.

Comment: Maybe it has not chosen you.

Comment: It might be scared that after all this time, it's just a pidgy.

Answer (score -2):

Well when you go out walking, be sure to go out in a STRAIGHT PATH. Try not to venture left or right. Just go down a road and take it to the end, as the gps system has shown to take your starting point, your end point (after x amount of minutes), and compute the shortest distance possible, disregarding walking along streets.

I haven't really experienced this issue of not hatching, or I haven't noticed it. Perhaps its also just your connection that suffers, or perhaps its really a bug. Either way, I've never had an egg stall for more than a day like this.
(Edit)

I know this system is weird and unusual, but it's been reported that way. It's like the different between Distance and Displacement, in physics terms. You run a lap around a track. Distance says you ran 400m, but Displacement says you ran 0m because you're in the same spot.

http://comicbook.com/2016/07/21/pokemon-go-eggs-may-not-work-the-way-you-think/ This is just the first site I saw that mentions the tracking system, and the information is conclusive with reports.
If you need more information, just search "Pokemon Go eggs tracking system" in google. Click any page that relates to misconceptions/untold secrets/incorrect. These are the pages that acknowledge how the system is different from a normal GPS

Comment: Do you have a source on how the GPS calculates the distance? Because it shouldn't work like that.

Comment: Pages that say that, but not really that much in the way of proof.

Comment: Then you go out for walks and bring feedback of why these certain issues are present. Various sites are at least bringing awareness to problems that are acknowledged by somewhat observant people.